# No version mismatch, but I still have a java.lang.AbstractMethodError. Why?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

**{** Using Java 1.7 and the Oracle OCI driver 11.2.0.1.0 (JDBC 4) **}**

I get the error **java.lang.AbstractMethodError** for oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setCharacterStream,  oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setClob, etc.

I'm using pure JDBC (java.sql.*), no oracle-specific extensions, and so far, only the methods added in 1.6 (as noted in the API) are giving me this error.

I have no other version of Java or Oracle client installed. Every other variation of this question that I can find suggest that an old version of the Oracle client is the issue, but my (only) version appears to be the correct version.

Any suggestions on what else to look for to understand the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The ojdbc6.jar had been added to the CLASSPATH for this application, while the ORACLE_HOME/bin folder had been added to the PATH. I assume there was a conflict, cleaning up the unneeded reference from the CLASSPATH sorted this issue out.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem and resolved it. Its root is the commons-dbcp library not suitable to the using JDBC driver.

To resolve this problem, you should upgrade ***commons-dbcp*** library to latest version (1.4). It will work with latest JDBC drivers correctly.

Cheers, TM

Comment: That may be true for the commons-dbcp library, but I'm not using it. Sorry.